# Grid Size in Spring batch

Tags: java, spring, spring-batch

I have batch job which reads data from bulk files, process it and insert in DB.

I'm using spring's partitioning features using the default partition handler.

```
    <bean class="org.spr...TaskExecutorPartitionHandler">
          <property name="taskExecutor" ref="taskExecutor"/>
          <property name="step" ref="readFromFile" />
          <property name="gridSize" value="10" />
    </bean>
```

What is the significance of the `gridSize` here ? I have configured in such a way that it is equal to the concurrency in taskExecutor.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`gridSize` specifies the number of `data blocks` to create to be processed by (usually) the same number of `workers`. Think about it as a number of mapped data blocks in a map/reduce.

Using a `StepExecutionSplitter`, given the data, `PartitionHandler` "partitions" / splits the data to a `gridSize` parts, and sends each part to an independent worker => `thread` in your case.

For example, you have 10 rows in DB that need to be processed. If you set the `gridSize` to be **5**, and you are using a straightforward partition logic, you'd end up with 10 / 5 = 2 rows per thread => **5** threads working concurrently on 2 rows each.

Comment: In that case gridSize has to be a dynamic one (intead of hardcoding to 10 ) which will be configured at runtime depending on the number of splits right ? So how do I pass the number of split information to the TaskExecutorPartitionHandler ?

Comment: I mean something like <beans:property name="gridSize" value="#{stepExecutionContext['numberOfSplits']}"></beans:property> or <beans:property name="gridSize" value="#{jobParameters['numberOfSplits']}"></beans:property> . But numberof splits is not determined before starting the job.

Comment: not sure I understand what you mean by `gridSize has to be a dynamic one`. You can define it in a property file ( `grid-size="${job.grid.size}"` ), and then drive the number of threads that will be spawned through that. Number of splits are actually determined _by_ the `gridSize`.

Comment: my doubt is, in that case number of splits remain same irrespective of the size of the file (because splits are determined by grid size , which is constant). Is that should be the case ideally ?

Comment: Spring Batch as a framework would not _estimate_ the number of threads needed to process the file, since this knowledge may depend on many business / other factors. If you have `something` that determines a file size and the number of threads _before_ the job runs, you can surely set `gridSize` dynamically: <beans:property name="gridSize" value="#{jobParameters['numberOfThreads']}">. In general, think about the `gridSize` as the size of a "real" grid with different nodes / hosts. Threads is just one of many _examples_ of a grid.

Answer (score 2):

Per the API,

> Passed to the StepExecutionSplitter in the
>   handle(StepExecutionSplitter, StepExecution) method, instructing it
>   how many StepExecution instances are required, ideally. The
>   StepExecutionSplitter is allowed to ignore the grid size in the case
>   of a restart, since the input data partitions must be preserved.

Answer (score 0):

grid size is nothing but set of task (assume as sack of bags ) a single partitioned step will lift for processing. After done with all taken task( sack of bags) it will come back for next set of task (sack of bags).