# Processing huge data with spring batch partitioning

Tags: spring, spring-batch

I am implementing spring batch job for processing millions of records in a DB table using partition approach as follows -

1. Fetch a unique partitioning codes from table in a partitioner and set the same in execution context.
2. Create a chunk step with reader,processor and writer to process records based on particular partition code.

Is this approach is proper or is there any better approach for situation like this? As some partition codes can have more number of records than others,so those with more records might take more time to process than the ones with less records.

Is it possible to create partition/thread to process like thread1 process 1-1000,thread2 process 1001-2000 etc ?

How do I control number of threads getting created as partition codes can be around 100, I would like to create only 20 thread and process in 5 iteration?

What happens if one partition fails, will all processing stop and reverted back?

Following are configurations -

```
 <bean id="MyPartitioner" class="com.MyPartitioner" />
 <bean id="itemProcessor" class="com.MyProcessor" scope="step" />
 <bean id="itemReader" class="org.springframework.batch.item.database.JdbcCursorItemReader" scope="step" >
  <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
  <property name="sql" value="select * from mytable WHERE code = '#{stepExecutionContext[code]}' "/>
  <property name="rowMapper">
      <bean class="com.MyRowMapper" scope="step"/>
  </property>
</bean>
<bean id="taskExecutor" class="org.springframework.scheduling.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor" >
    <property name="corePoolSize" value="20"/>
    <property name="maxPoolSize" value="20"/>
    <property name="allowCoreThreadTimeOut" value="true"/>
</bean>

<batch:step id="Step1" xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/batch">
    <batch:tasklet transaction-manager="transactionManager">
        <batch:chunk reader="itemReader"  processor="itemProcessor" writer="itemWriter" commit-interval="200"/>
    </batch:tasklet>
</batch:step>
<batch:job id="myjob">
    <batch:step id="mystep">
        <batch:partition step="Step1" partitioner="MyPartitioner">
            <batch:handler grid-size="20" task-executor="taskExecutor"/>
        </batch:partition>
    </batch:step>
</batch:job>
```

Partitioner -

```
public class MyPartitioner implements Partitioner{
@Override
public Map<String, ExecutionContext> partition(int gridSize)
{
Map<String, ExecutionContext> partitionMap = new HashMap<String, ExecutionContext>();
List<String> codes = getCodes();

for (String code : codes)
{
    ExecutionContext context = new ExecutionContext();
    context.put("code", code);
    partitionMap.put(code, context);
}
return partitionMap;}}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would say it is right approach, I do not see why you need to have one thread per 1000 items, if you partition per unique partitioning codes and have chunk of 1000 items you will have transactions on 1000 items per thread which is IMO ok.

1. In addition to saving unique partitioning codes you can count how
   many you have of each partition code and partition even more, by
   creating new subcontext for every 1000 of same partition code (that
   way for partition code that has i.e. 2200 records you will invoke 3
   threads with context params: 1=> partition_key=key1, skip=0,
   count=1000, 2=>partition_key=key1, skip=1000, count=1000 and
   3=>partition_key=key1, skip=2000, count=1000) if that is what you
   want but I would still go without it
2. Number of threads is controlled with `ThreadPoolTaskExecutor` which is passed to partition step when you create it. You have method `setCorePoolSize()` which you can set on 20 and you will get at most 20 threads. Next fine grain configuration is `grid-size` which tells how many partitions will be created out of full partition map. Here is [explanation of grid size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7759156/grid-size-in-spring-batch). So partitioning is about dividing the work. After that, your threading configuration will define the concurrency of the actual processing.
3. If one partition fails whole partitioned step fails with information which partition failed. Success partitions are done and would not be invoked again and when job restarts it will pick up where it left off by redoing failed and non processed partitions.

Hope I picked up all questions you had since there were many.

**Example of case 1** - maybe there are mistakes but just to get idea:

```
public class MyPartitioner implements Partitioner{
@Override
public Map<String, ExecutionContext> partition(int gridSize)
{
    Map<String, ExecutionContext> partitionMap = new HashMap<String, ExecutionContext>();
    Map<String, int> codesWithCounts = getCodesWithCounts();

    for (Entry<String, int> codeWithCount : codesWithCounts.entrySet())
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < codeWithCount.getValue(); i + 1000){
            ExecutionContext context = new ExecutionContext();
            context.put("code", code);
            context.put("skip", i);
            context.put("count", 1000);
            partitionMap.put(code, context);
        }
    }
    return partitionMap;
}
```

Adn than you page by 1000 and you get from context how many you should skip which will in example of 2200 be: 0, 1000, 2000.

Comment: I see you're new to SO. If you feel an answer solved the problem, please mark it as 'accepted' by clicking the green check mark. I saw on other thread regarding passing data to `JdbcCursorItemReader` that you did not mark it and you said it managed to fix the problem.

Comment: Thank you for the reply and addressing all questions. I couldn't understand point 1, can you please suggest how do I achieve what you suggested? And with ThreadPoolTaskExecutor if I set corePoolSize and maxPoolSize as 20 along with partitioner grid size as 10, what will happen when number of partition code is 100, will it create 100 threads each processing specific number of records per code sequentially? I updated question with my configuration details.

Comment: How do you get list of codes and is there a way to find out how many items you have by each code upfront in partitioner?

Comment: I accepted both answers, thank you. I either fetch from a table or a properties file, unless I query my main table in DB based on partition code I can't find out number of records/items per code upfront. As of now I pass this code to itemreader and there this query will be executed.

Comment: I added better explanation of grid size and trhead pool, hope it helps. In your example you will get 10 partitions of 10 partition codes, and 20 threads will work on them (most probably only 10 threads working on 10 items per partition in parallel). For first part I do not see a way then, I thought you can fetch number of records per partition code up front by querying DB for count only.

Comment: If i fetch count of records per code in partitioner how do I partition based on it?

Comment: @NenadBozic - Could you please guide me here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61827296/spring-batch-how-to-reads-5-million-records-in-faster-ways?