# Spring batch partitioning: set grid-size at runtime

Tags: spring, spring-batch

Should the grid-size of the partition be the same as the size of Map returned by Partitioner.partition() method?

In my spring batch partitioning scenario, there are 2 steps. The first step identifies the total number of records to be processed and the second step (which is a partitioned step based on TaskExecutorPartitionHandler) processes the records in batches of 1000.

If there are 20500 records, the size of Map returned by Partitioner.partition() method is 21 and 21 concurrent step executions will be needed. Does that mean the grid-size of the partition should be 21 in this case?

What if the total number of records to be processed changes daily? How can the grid-size of the partition be allocated at run time after the completion of the first step?

Comment: This should help. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7759156/grid-size-in-spring-batch

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the first step can store the grid-size in jobExecutionContext

```
ExecutionContext jobExecutionContext =
chunkContext.getStepContext().getStepExecution().getJobExecution().getExecutionContext();

jobExecutionContext.putInt("gridSize", 21);
```

and it can later be injected into the PartitionHandler.

```
<job id="testJob" xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/batch">
    <step id="firstStep" next="secondStep.master">
       <tasklet ref="firstTasklet"/>
    </step>
    <step id="secondStep.master">
       <partition partitioner="partitioner" handler="taskExecutorPartitionHandler"/>
    </step>
</job>

<bean id="taskExecutorPartitionHandler" class="org.springframework.batch.core.partition.support.TaskExecutorPartitionHandler" scope="step">
    <property name="taskExecutor" ref="threadPoolTaskExecutor"/>
    <property name="step" ref="secondStep.slave" />
    <property name="gridSize" value="#{jobExecutionContext['gridSize']}" />
</bean>
```